# Rails: Is there an efficient way to get all whitelisted attributes with values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mass-assignment

I'm trying to use a model as a template to create a new model. However, I only want to use the `attr_accessible` attributes from the template model.

Here's what I'm doing now. It works, but it seems too complex.

```
def copy_attrs_and_errors(other)
  self.class.attr_accessible[:default].to_a.each do |attr|
    eval("self.#{attr} = other.#{attr}") unless attr.blank?
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to say something as simple as:

```
self.attributes = other.whitelist_attributes(:default)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: `.accessible_attributes` is synonymous with `.attr_accessible[:default]`, and I find it more readable.

Comment: Good point. That seems to take the role as a parameter and use `:default` by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it's a little crazy, but you could do something like this in a module or whatever:

```
def self.from_accessible_attributes(other)
  values     = other.attributes.values_at(*other.class.accessible_attributes)
  attributes = Hash[other.class.accessible_attributes.zip(values)]
  new(attributes)
end
```